# Ubuntu DHCPD won't start

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp-server

I upgraded today to Ubuntu 16.04, I know it's a long overdue upgrade. After the upgrade finished the ISC DHCP server stopped running.

It appears to be a permissions problem but I'm darned if I can figure it out.

I'm using the following command to test/start the server :

```
sudo /usr/sbin/dhcpd -user dhcpd -group dhcpd -f -4 -pf /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
```

And the resulting output is

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Config file: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
Database file: /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
PID file: /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid
Can't open lease database /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases: Permission denied --
  check for failed database rewrite attempt!
Please read the dhcpd.leases manual page if you
don't know what to do about this.
<snip>
```

One would think that it's just a matter of changing the ownership/permissions on the lease file, here are the existing permissions :

```
mike@wilma:~$ sudo ls -lad /var/lib/dhcp/ /var/lib/dhcp/*
drw-rw-r-- 2 dhcpd dhcpd   4096 Jul  3 23:02 /var/lib/dhcp/
-rw-r--r-- 1 dhcpd dhcpd      0 Aug  4  2016 /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dhcpd dhcpd 842233 Jul  3 11:55 /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
```

Making sure the user actually exists ...

```
@wilma:~$ id dhcpd
uid=112(dhcpd) gid=123(dhcpd) groups=123(dhcpd)
```

I've turned off apparmor for now so that's not the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Using systemctl ....

```
mike@wilma:~$ sudo systemctl restart isc-dhcp-server.service
[sudo] password for mike: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for mike:
```

Results from the log file

```
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma systemd[1]: Stopped ISC DHCP IPv4 server.
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma systemd[1]: Started ISC DHCP IPv4 server.
/usr/share/man/man8/dhcpd.8.gz
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma dhcpd[26877]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.3.3
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma sh[26877]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.3.3
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma sh[26877]: Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma sh[26877]: All rights reserved.
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma sh[26877]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma dhcpd[26877]: Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma dhcpd[26877]: All rights reserved.
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma dhcpd[26877]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma dhcpd[26877]: Config file: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma sh[26877]: Config file: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma sh[26877]: Database file: /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma sh[26877]: PID file: /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma dhcpd[26877]: Database file: /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma dhcpd[26877]: PID file: /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma dhcpd[26877]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.3.3
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma dhcpd[26877]: Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma dhcpd[26877]: All rights reserved.
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma dhcpd[26877]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma dhcpd[26877]: Can't chown new lease file: Operation not permitted
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma dhcpd[26877]: 
Jul  3 23:50:12 wilma sh[26877]: Can't chown new lease file: Operation not permitted
```

Permissions on the files are changed by the systemctl script :

```
mike@wilma:~$ sudo ls -lad /var/lib/dhcp/ /var/lib/dhcp/*
drwxrwxr-x 2 root  dhcpd   4096 Jul  3 23:50 /var/lib/dhcp/
-rw-r--r-- 1 dhcpd dhcpd      0 Aug  4  2016 /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root  dhcpd 842233 Jul  3 11:55 /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root       0 Jul  3 23:50 /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases.1562154612
```

Comment: Is the result the same as if you start the service via `systemctl`?

Comment: Added systemctl info to the original post

Comment: Is the directory itself (/var/lib/dhcpd) readable by dhcpd?

Comment: That depends on how the server is invoked, if it's invoked directly from the command line, then yes. If it's invoked from systemctl then it is initially then gets chown'd to root.dhcpd and 755. See the sudo ls -lad results above

Comment: Local time 12:19am. I'll be back in a few hours

Answer (score 1):

It may be a known bug you ran into for 4.3.3:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/isc-dhcp/+bug/1186662

It may be easiest to upgrade ISC.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank all of you for putting some time and effort in to helping me out. The problem somehow resolved itself, I'm afraid I can't give a reason, it just started working again.
The syslog shows leases being given without problem.

Again, thanks :)